# Octave symbolic packag fails to import SymPy

Tags: octave

I get an error message when I try to make use of `symbolic` package in Octave.

```
>> pkg load symbolic
>> syms x y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sympy
OctSymPy v2.6.0: this is free software without warranty, see source.
Initializing communication with SymPy using a popen2() pipe.
error: Python cannot import SymPy: have you installed SymPy?
error: called from
    assert_have_python_and_sympy at line 37 column 5
    python_ipc_popen2 at line 78 column 5
    python_ipc_driver at line 59 column 13
    python_cmd at line 164 column 9
    valid_sym_assumptions at line 38 column 10
    assumptions at line 82 column 7
    syms at line 97 column 13
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the error message really contains all you need. Have you tried to read it?

Comment: @Andy Yes, of course. I don't understand what should I do.

Comment: Do you have installed SymPy and do you think it's just not detected (so python is wrong)? Or is Python right and you haven't installed it? If this is the case you have to install it... (this of course depends on your used OS)

Comment: @Andy : Thanks for your time. I have Python installed.  Through anaconda distribution. (Ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: This was not my question. Do you have "SymPy" installed?

Comment: Sorry. I apologize! I should have said : "I have SymPy installed".

Comment: Obviously you haven't installed SymPy in a way so that python is able to find it. Please follow the install instructions for your operating system

Comment: @Andy : `> $ pip install --user sympy
Requirement already satisfied: sympy in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.1.1)`

Comment: @Andy: I finally solve the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: in this case you should add your solution as answer for others